# How to show ApiMember attribute data for properties of complex types on ServiceStack's generated metadata page

Tags: c#, servicestack

Is it possible to have ApiMember attribute data show up on ServiceStack generated metadata for properties of complex types on the request DTO? If so, how can this be achieved?

Let's say I have a request DTO with the following properties:

```
public Customer Customer { get; set; }        
public List<CustomerOrder> CustomerOrders { get; set; }
```

and a customer type with the following properties:

```
public string Id { get; set; }      
public string CompanyName { get; set; }     
public string ContactName { get; set; }
```

I would like to be able to add the ApiMember attribute to the customer's properties. However, when I do so, the metadata page for the request DTO does not show the customer's properties.

I would also like the CustomerOrder's properties to be shown on the metadata page as well. I realize this could be a little trickier due to it being a list of the CustomerOrder type.

If this is not supported, recommendations for other options are welcome.

Comment: Have you seen ServiceStack's Swagger support? https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API. I think this is a really nice way to handle documentation.

Comment: @paaschpa: I have seen it and am going to try it, but wanted to get the basic metadata pages working as expected first. If the Swagger API picks up the ApiMember attribute for properties on complex types, then that sounds like an acceptable solution. Can anyone confirm if the Swagger API can handle the scenario given above? If no one can confirm, I'll give it a try and post an update when time permits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you're looking for is supported at the moment. I think the `Api` and `ApiMember` attributes are meant to follow/mirror  the [Swagger API and DataTypes](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Datatypes). In the Swagger API there is support for `complex` types but in order get the details of a complex type it needs to be in the `models` section of the API declaration. I don't think `models` is currently handled within ServiceStack. At least, I haven't stumbled across it [within the code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/SwaggerApiService.cs)

Comment: Right, not all Swagger attributes are have made it in the Metadata pages yet (pull-reqs are welcomed! :) - but this is on our TODO list so should be available shortly.